# Weird version conflict: The type 'CrontabSchedule' exists in both 'NCrontab.Signed, Version=3.2.20120.0' and 'NCrontab, Version=3.2.20120.0'

Tags: c#, version-compatibility, ncron

I am trying do a very simple thing in console app:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers;
using NCrontab;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nCrontabSchedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse("5 4 * * * *");
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0433  The type 'CrontabSchedule' exists in both 'NCrontab.Signed, Version=3.2.20120.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5247b4370afff365' and 'NCrontab, Version=3.2.20120.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'    ConsoleApp3 C:\Users\bowmanzh\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs   12  Active
```

It didn't even finish compile! It’s hard for me to understand what’s going on here, I just want to use a simple thing.

Why is there a version conflict here? In fact, I referenced two packages, this is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="NCrontab" Version="3.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have already googled, they say something like Aliases, but in fact on my side it doesn't have this property.

I have already tried:

```
using v2 = NCrontab;
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            v2.CrontabSchedule nCrontabSchedule = v2.CrontabSchedule.Parse("5 4 * * *");
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you so much for taking the time to check!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem.  Trying unstalling the NCrontab nuget package and installing NCrontab.Signed instead.  This resolved the issue for me.